# Localhost vs 127.0.0.1 - Error when referring to own IP address for an application running on IIS

Tags: wordpress, asp.net, ip-address, localhost, windows-server-2008

I have an ASP.net application which I've been playing around with on my Windows 2008 server. I have WordPress installed so that when I visit the server by it's IP address I can visit my hosted website.

The WordPress website works fine when I request the site by it's IP, but when I try to debug the ASP.net application in visual studio it opens `http://localhost:49219/`, where I can see my asp.net website, but even after opening this port and trying to access my application over the net by my server's IP I get the following error:

[image: Bad Request - Invalid Hostname]

What is strange is that even on my server, I cannot visit the site by typing in `http://127.0.0.1:49219/`.

I'd like to try to get this application on the net but I really have no clue why I can refer to it using localhost but not by IP. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around for some time, I think I figured it out. The service I was running was on visual studio's debug server, so it was probably redirecting the request for localhost on that port to itself, however 127.0.0.1 probably can't be remapped in the same way. Everything worked correctly after the site was published.